# How to auto disable "Enabled for Site" for certain sites (or groups) when creating a new entry

Tags: craft3, multi-site, sites

We have a mutli-country/language website with Craft 3 for many countries/languages.

When we create an entry (ecommerce product to be exact) in the English sites we dont want to enable it for other language sites as we would not have the content yet. We only want it enabled for English.

If we disable "Enabled for Site" in the new entry, this does not carry over onto the other sites, the other sites entry are all Enabled for Site.

So we have to go into every languages's entry and disable Enabled for Site to disable it for other languages.

Trouble is we have a lot of languages, its a real pain to have to do this each time.

Ideally when an entry is created we should be able to somehow choose its only enabled for this site OR group the site is in (we group languages by Site groups). Or choose sites or groups to not enable.

Does anyone know how we can auto set it to disabled for all the non-English groups when we create a new entry?

Thanks